# Extra Carriage Returns while reading CSV

Tags: java, regex, csv, carriage-return

I have some CSV files that I am trying to parse using Java. I first extract a single row from the CSV file and send it to another method for processing with the following code:

```
for (String tempFile : filesToBeRead) {
        File csvFile = new File(tempFile);
        Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(csvFile);            
        scanner.useDelimiter("[\n\r]");
        scanner.next();         
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            String temp = scanner.next();
            System.out.println(temp);
//          dataStorage.enterRow(temp);

            }
        }
```

The output of the above code is:

```
AI277|DEL|MUB|05-12-2013|0600|4.10|5500|Y|EB

AI279|DEL|MUB|10-12-2013|0630|4.30|4900|Y|E

AI289|DEL|MUB|10-12-2013|0830|4.00|5650|Y|EB

AI278|DEL|MUB|17-12-2013|1830|4.20|5300|Y|E

AI278|DEL|MUB|20-12-2013|1430|3.45|6500|N|EB
```

Where as the output should have been:

```
AI277|DEL|MUB|05-12-2013|0600|4.10|5500|Y|EB    
AI279|DEL|MUB|10-12-2013|0630|4.30|4900|Y|E    
AI289|DEL|MUB|10-12-2013|0830|4.00|5650|Y|EB    
AI278|DEL|MUB|17-12-2013|1830|4.20|5300|Y|E
AI278|DEL|MUB|20-12-2013|1430|3.45|6500|N|EB
```

What exactly is happening and where is this extra carriage return (\r) coming from even though the regex is set appropriately?

Comment: Use `System.out.print`

Answer (score 2):

The below regex would match one or more newline character or carriage return,

```
"[\n\r]+"
```

Just set the above regex as delimiter. That is change this `scanner.useDelimiter("[\n\r]");` line  to ,

```
scanner.useDelimiter("[\n\r]+");
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it! Any specific reason as to why this extra '\r' is occuring

Comment: It's may because of blank lines.

Comment: No. Its a regular CSV file

Comment: May be it contains both `\n` and `\r`